# Why is using EXTRACT EPOCH giving the same result for two different timestamp inputs?

Tags: sql, netezza

I am running an EPOCH with different dates. But both are giving me same output. Why?

```
select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM AGE('2016-04-26 00:00:00','2016-03-27 00:00:00'));

select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM AGE('2016-04-26 00:00:00','2016-03-26 00:00:00'));
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4):

If you run the age query by itself

```
select AGE('2016-04-26 00:00:00','2016-03-27 00:00:00')
, AGE('2016-04-26 00:00:00','2016-03-26 00:00:00')
```

You will find the result is 
`30 days and 1 month`

If you are more precise and compare the same intervals you should achieve the intended result.

```
select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp('2016-03-27 00:00:00') - timestamp('2016-04-26 00:00:00')))
, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp('2016-03-26 00:00:00') - timestamp('2016-04-26 00:00:00')))
```